# JavaScript hide/Visible script doesnt hide after 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my script, when I click for hide a div, it's doesn't works. But for make visible a div its works perfectly.

Can you explain me and help me pls ?

```
function visibilite(id) {
        var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(var no=0;no<divs.length;no++){
            if(divs[ no].className=='divs bouton' || divs[ no].className=='divs'){ // Target div which called "divs" OR called "divs bouton"
                divs[ no].style.display = "none"; // hide them all
            }
        }   
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"; // visible
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<head>
    <link href="ress/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/baseScript.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
     .divs {display:none;padding:5px;margin:10px;}
    /*]]>*/
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function visibilite(id) {
        var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(var no=0;no<divs.length;no++){
            if(divs[ no].className=='divs bouton' || divs[ no].className=='divs'){ // Target div which called "divs" OR called "divs bouton"
                divs[ no].style.display = "none"; // hide them all
            }
        }   
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"; // visible
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>




<body>

    <div style="width:250px;margin:auto;" class="txtlinks" id ="headontainer">
            <div class="col marginR">
                <a style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" href ="#">Installation Kit</a><a href ="#">FAQs</a><br />
            </div>
    </div>



    <div style="width:700px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" id ="maincontainer">

            <div style="padding-bottom:75px;" onmouseover="this.style.border='1px solid blue'" onmouseout="this.style.border='0px'" id="work_1" >
                <a style="text-transform:none;" href="javascript:visibilite('opt1');">
                <div>
                  <span class="blctxt blueblc">Getting to know Office 365</span>
                  <br />
                  <span style="color: rgb(80, 81, 80); font-family: 'segoe ui', arial, tahoma; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none;">
                  Check out see some of the ways Office 365 can help people get things done,
                  better, together</span>.
                </div>
                </a>
                <div id="opt1" class="divs bouton">
                    <br />
                    <br />                      
                    <a style="text-decoration: none; color:white;" href="http://aka.ms/o365booklet" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @kykerz - plz post here what you tried till now ? and post HTML code also.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write this:

```
function visibilite() {
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('divs');
        var bouton = document.getElementsByClassName('bouton');
        if(divs.style.display == 'hidden' || bouton.style.display == 'hidden')
         {
        bouton.style.display = "block";
        divs.style.display = "block"; // visible
        }
        else{
bouton.style.display = "hidden";
        divs.style.display = "hidden"; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can u be more explicit and say what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I want hide/show many divs with many buttons. the script you can see before, you can only show hidden divs but once time you click for show them, you cant hide them.

Comment: Sadly i cant see the button which triggers this. Can you tell me where your button is?

Comment: ofc, it is the 
<a style="text-transform:none;" href="javascript:visibilite('opt1');"............

</span>.
                </div>
                </a>

Comment: Try to change it to href="javascript:visibilite();"

Comment: And how you tell it which divs appear ?

Comment: You do this via the document.getElementsByClass. All of these Elements will be hidden and shown then.